# Avoid col's 32KB length limit

Tags: linux, bash, shell, text

I use python to screen-scrape a lot of text from routers and switches, and record the sessions with [script](http://linux.die.net/man/1/script).  Normally I clean up the [script](http://linux.die.net/man/1/script) sessions with:

```
touch a_clean_script_file.txt; col -bx <a_script_file.tmp > a_clean_script_file.txt
```

For reasons I don't want to get into, I discovered a problem with this; [col](http://linux.die.net/man/1/col) has a maximum limit of 32KB per line<sup>1</sup>:

```
[mpenning@hostname tmp]$ ### 128KB characters, using normal shell pipes
[mpenning@hostname tmp]$ printf 'z%.0s' {1..131072} | wc -c
131072
[mpenning@hostname tmp]$ ### 128KB characters, using col (limited to 32KB) <----
[mpenning@hostname tmp]$ printf 'z%.0s' {1..131072} | col -bx | wc -c
32769
[mpenning@hostname tmp]$
```

Obviously I can use `split -b` to solve this problem, but now I'm creating many tiny files and executing `col` on every one of them.  As a long-shot, I tried buffering through [mbuffer](http://www.maier-komor.de/mbuffer.html) (`mbuffer -s 8192`) and [stdbuf](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stdbuf), but those obviously didn't help the situation.

#### Question

Is there either:

- An alternative to [col](http://linux.die.net/man/1/col) that doesn't have the 32KB per line limits?
- A way to split the long text lines, without writing to many temporary files via [split](http://linux.die.net/man/1/split)?<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>At least it's 32KB on my systems, `uname -a` ⇒ `Linux hostname 2.6.32-431.1.2.0.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Dec 13 13:06:13 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`</sub>
<sup>2</sup> <sub>I realize I can [split](http://linux.die.net/man/1/split) into `/dev/shm` to eliminate some disk latencies, but I'd like to avoid [split](http://linux.die.net/man/1/split) altogether if possible.</sub>

Comment: Great self-documenting question. While the `-l` option is about lines, ,it might be worth using it with a value like 2*128 to see if that changes your error boundaries (Default for -l (on my Linux) is 128 lines). Good luck!

Comment: @shellter, that's an interesting idea... I tried `printf 'z%.0s' {1..131072} | col -bx -l 2147483647 | wc -c`, but that still gives me the same results as `col -bx`.  `-l 2147483647` seems to be the max value for my `col` (CentOS 6.5)

Comment: For what its worth, your linux version is (almost) irrelevant; what would be relevant would be the version of `col` installed on your system, which is not related to the linux kernel. It is related to the distribution you use, but it would be more direct to just specify the version string from the `col` utility itself. (However, it's quite likely that your `col` doesn't report a version string, in which case the fallback would be the package version. (If you use debian/ubuntu, `dpkg -S /usr/bin/col` will tell you the package name. Then `dpkg -l <pkgname>` shows the version).

Comment: @rici, I'm running CentOS 6.5, and `col` comes from `util-linux-ng-2.17.2-12.14.el6.x86_64`.  AFAICT, I'm exposed to the bug...

Comment: @MikePennington: I'm certain you are, since your version of `col` truncates output. Aside from the CPPFLAGS assignment, which might not be needed on your system, you should be able to compile yourself a `col` using the same steps I did on ubuntu. (In the case of `col`, ncurses is actually irrelevant, so `./configure --without-ncurses` would be fine if just `./configure` fails to find the ncurses headers.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug in `col`. (I've reported it, for what its worth, to [FreeBSD](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/query-pr.cgi?pr=186282) and to [Debian](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=737159) (which should also apply to Ubuntu); feel free to broadcast the report to other distributions which might have their own source repositories.).

As far as I can see, the bug is present in all the commonly available versions of the `col` utility, even the OpenBSD version.

There is a simple fix in the bug report, which is to change the declaration of `c_column` from `short` to `int`. I tested this by downloading the debian `util-linux` [source package](http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/u/util-linux/util-linux_2.20.1.orig.tar.gz)<sup>1</sup>, and then compiled it (on an `ubuntu` system) using the following commands, starting in the directory in which I downloaded the tarball:

```
tar xf util-linux_2.20.1.orig.tar.gz
cd util-linux_2.20.1
CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/include/ncursesw ./configure
cd text-utils
# edit line 81 of text-utils/col.c, s/short/int/
make col
```

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>For what it's worth, I only found out afterwards that this is not the source for the debian `col` utility; the main difference I see is this one reports its version string with the `-V` option</sub>